# Java - including an external library

Tags: java, javafx, codec

I've included an external library called commons codec, but can not import it in my project. Following formula:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

does not work.

ps. Screenshow of file explorer:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKLuK.png)

Comment: Probably you need to import the jar, not the directory containing the jar (unless the directory you linked contains the class files...)

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are Netbeans. It looks like you have the entire folder of the external library in your library folder. Try importing the .jar file ONLY in your external library folder. If you have any more trouble let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netbeans, then right-click the `Libraries` of your `Project` and select `Add JAR/Folder` option in it.
Navigate to the folder/JAR file and click OK
`Clean and Build` the Project

(I suggest to import `JAR File` to the project as it is easy to read by the JVM)